# How do I Add HTML to the_excerpt() & the_content() Output?

Tags: php, the-content, excerpt

I am building a theme where I need to add a dropcap to the first letter. This would be done by surrounding the character in question with `<span class="dropcap>` and `</span>`. The actual work of making the dropcap will be done using [Adobe's Dropcap.js](http://webplatform.adobe.com/dropcap.js/).

I would like to do this for the output of `the_excerpt()` for sure. In addition I would also like to add this span tag to the first character of every Paragraph element that is a sibling of an H3 element (h3 + p).

My preference is to do this with PHP as opposed to writing a JavaScript or jQuery script to parse the document and insert it.

So far I have only tested this using `the_excerpt()` and it was an utter failure resulting in a Fatal error about allocated memory exhausted. But here is the code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'test_excerpt_dropcap' ) ) :
function test_excerpt_dropcap() {
    global $post;
    $the_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    if ( is_singular() && has_excerpt() ) {
        $the_excerpt = 
        preg_replace('/^(.)/', '<span class="dropcap">\1</span>', $the_excerpt);
    }
    return $the_excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'test_excerpt_dropcap' );
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_excerpt()` returns the excerpt, but only [after applying `get_the_excerpt` filters to it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt#Return_Values). This causes infinite recursion, as your filter handler will be called to an infinite depth.

Of course, the best solution is the css one (see @spacegrrl's answer), but if you have your reasons for keeping that `<span>`, please note that the excerpt can be passed as a parameter to your handler. Just add an `$the_excerpt` parameter and use that, instead of calling `get_the_excerpt()`.

Comment: Is there any way to stop it from infinitely looping? I did figure out a solution that works without a filter that simply just takes the output from `get_the_excerpt()` and then calls `preg_replace()` and returns that value but I would like to see if I can do it as a filter.

Comment: As I said, don't call `get_the_excerpt()` from within your handler. Use the parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't have my coffee yet so my brain muddled your response. I passed $the_excerpt into the handler and it worked perfectly. Am I correct in thinking modifying `the_content()` output for h3 + p like I want is a bit complicated to do with PHP and should just be done with JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: I don't see the complication. Maybe you should try it, and if you "fail", ask another, relevant, question about it. But I trust you will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with CSS only.

Provided there's a class that will let you select the excerpt, you can then use further CSS pseudo-classes to select the first letter of the first paragraph.

```
.excerpt p:first-of-type::first-letter {
   /* dropcap styling */
}
```

[first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type), [first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

Using a sibling selector can get you the first p tag after every h3, for the second task:

```
.content h3 + p::first-letter {
   /* dropcap styling */
}
```

[adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Comment: I actually will be using Adobe's Dropcap.js to handle the actual styling since it is a bit more cleaner than straight up CSS.